# Setup a server on my laptop/desktop for app

Tags: mongodb, apache, server, parse-server

I want to setup a server as a backend for my android/web app with mongodb(nosql) (Just like Firebase) on my own laptop/desktop with all the functionality and API.

I read something about creating a server with apache but not sure what to do.

And please tell if there is anything to do of parse server.

Can anyone suggest a video or give great description for this.

Answer (score 1):

Parse Server needs NodeJS not Apache.

Make sure you have installed NodeJs and git to your computer first.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server-example Other steps are written in page. Follow the steps one by one

Comment: Some of the details may be outdated but if you prefer a video you could check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o522ovITvW4), it shows the process of setting up a Parse Server locally using the example project.